# Is it possible to browse files on a powered-off Android devices from a PC?

Tags: sony-xperia-z

My Sony Xperia Z doesn't boot, so I may need to flash it, but I want to have a backup from files on internal storage before flashing.

Is it possible to connect (Android) phone to a PC while it's powered off and browse files on the phone?

Comment: If it's turned off, it's turned off -- so you can connect the cable fine, but nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

No, while the phone's powered off you can't read the files on it. If your bootloader is already unlocked, you might be able to find a custom recovery that just lets you mount as a USB drive. In that case, booting into the recovery would be sufficient even if the main OS doesn't boot. Of course, if your bootloader isn't unlocked, unlocking it to flash a custom recovery would wipe the storage anyway.